# Java stream groupingBy and sum multiple fields

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, grouping

Here is my List fooList

```
class Foo {
    private String name;
    private int code;
    private int account;
    private int time;
    private String others;

    ... constructor, getters & setters
}
```

e.g.(all the value of account has been set to 1)

```
new Foo(First, 200, 1, 400, other1), 
new Foo(First, 200, 1, 300, other1),
new Foo(First, 201, 1, 10, other1),
new Foo(Second, 400, 1, 20, other2),
new Foo(Second, 400, 1, 40, other2),
new Foo(Third, 100, 1, 200, other3),
new Foo(Third, 101, 1, 900, other3)
```

I want to transform these values by grouping "name" and "code", accounting for the number, and summing the "time", e.g.

```
new Foo(First, 200, 2, 700, other1), 
new Foo(First, 201, 1, 10, other1),
new Foo(Second, 400, 2, 60, other2),
new Foo(Third, 100, 1, 200, other3),
new Foo(Third, 101, 1, 900, other3)
```

I know that I should use a stream like this:

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> map = fooList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Foo::getName()));
```

but how can I group them by code then do the accounting and summing job?

---

Also, what if I want to calculate the average time? e.g.

```
new Foo(First, 200, 2, 350, other1), 
new Foo(First, 201, 1, 10, other1),
new Foo(Second, 400, 2, 30, other2),
new Foo(Third, 100, 1, 200, other3),
new Foo(Third, 101, 1, 900, other3)
```

Can I use both of `summingInt(Foo::getAccount)` and `averagingInt(Foo::getTime)` instead?

Comment: Why your name is String when you pass Integer values?

Comment: maybe I should rename it in a better way@MrFisherman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround could be to deal with `grouping` with key as `List` and casting while mapping back to object type.

```
List<Foo> result = fooList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(foo ->
                        Arrays.asList(foo.getName(), foo.getCode(), foo.getAccount()),
                Collectors.summingInt(Foo::getTime)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new Foo((String) entry.getKey().get(0),
                (Integer) entry.getKey().get(1),
                entry.getValue(),
                (Integer) entry.getKey().get(2)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Cleaner way would be to expose APIs for merge function and performing a `toMap`.

---

**Edit**: The simplification with `toMap` would look like the following

```
List<Foo> result = new ArrayList<>(fooList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(foo -> Arrays.asList(foo.getName(), foo.getCode()),
                Function.identity(), Foo::aggregateTime))
        .values());
```

where the `aggregateTime` is a static method within `Foo` such as this :

```
static Foo aggregateTime(Foo initial, Foo incoming) {
    return new Foo(incoming.getName(), incoming.getCode(),
            incoming.getAccount(), initial.getTime() + incoming.getTime());
}
```

Comment: It seems that I can't do ```return new Foo(incoming.getName(),incoming.getCode(),incoming.getAccount(), initial.getTime() + incoming.getTime());``` because of ```required: no arguments```

Comment: @San.s that just needs an appropriate constructor.

Comment: I'm totally beginner in Java, would you mind teaching me how to do that? Thank you. Also it's kind of confused to me about calculating the average time.@Naman

Comment: @San.s What I did there was to iterate through the list and find out elements that are the same based on few attributes. Next, I have defined a merge function `aggregateTime` which takes two such similar objects and results into a merged final object (based on whatever intended logic). If your expectation is to average the time as well, then you would have to for once iterate the complete list and then evaluated the average of values found matching. But, that wouldn't be the same as `summing` which doesn't need an awareness of the number of elements traversed.

Comment: I see..So It's better to merge an object which has got the number of grouped```name```and```code``` , and summed ```time```, then do a single division to get the average time. Am I right? Also I wanna know what is **an appropriate constructor** looks like. Thanks a lot! @Naman

Comment: @San.s Yes, to get an average, sum with division by size can help. Another way would be to write your custom collector for something similar. By appropriate constructor I meant, that accepts all the arguments as shared in the POJO as in the question. (excluding the `others`). The intent is to create a new instance with the specified values.

Comment: @Naman I followed your approach but I couldn't fix my issue. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74511911/java-streams-not-filtering-multiple-condition-groupby-with-counting-and-sum

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own collect mechanish that might look like following

```java
        var collect = Stream.of(
                new Foo(1, 200, 1, 400),
                new Foo(1, 200, 1, 300),
                new Foo(1, 201, 1, 10),
                new Foo(2, 400, 1, 20),
                new Foo(2, 400, 1, 40),
                new Foo(3, 100, 1, 200),
                new Foo(3, 101, 1, 900)
        )
                .collect(
                        ArrayList::new,
                        (BiConsumer<ArrayList<Foo>, Foo>) (foos, foo) -> {
                            var newFoo = foos
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(f -> f.name == foo.name && f.account == foo.account)
                                    .findFirst()
                                    .map(f -> new Foo(f.name, f.code, f.account + foo.account, f.time + foo.time))
                                    .orElse(foo);
                            foos.removeIf(f -> f.name == foo.name && f.account == foo.account);
                            foos.add(newFoo);
                        },
                        (foos, foos2) -> foos.addAll(foos2)
                );
```

Comment: I declared `name` as `int`. Anyway that's just a draft

Comment: I followed your approach but I couldn't fix my issue. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74511911/java-streams-not-filtering-multiple-condition-groupby-with-counting-and-sum