# How to I get aggregated object list from repeated fields of object collection with stream lambda

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

```
class ProductTitle {

    private Long productId;

    private String productName

    private String sellerName

    private Long categoryId;

    private Long titleId;

    private int status;

    private String title; 

    private Long titlePrice;

}

class Aggregate {
    productId;
    productName;
    sellerName;
    categoryId;
    List<TitleInfo> titles;
}

class TitleInfo {
    titleId;
    status;
    title;
}

SampleData:
productId:1, productname: "product1", sellerName: "seller1",categoryId:2, titleId:25, status:1, title:title1
productId:1, productname: "product1", sellerName: "seller1",categoryId:2, titleId:23, status:1, title:title2
productId:1, productname: "product1", sellerName: "seller1",categoryId:2, titleId:45, status:1, title:title3
productId:2, productname: "product2", sellerName: "seller2",categoryId:5, titleId:67, status:0, title:title4
productId:2, productname: "product2", sellerName: "seller2",categoryId:5, titleId:11, status:1, title:title5
productId:3, productname: "product3", sellerName: "seller3",categoryId:9, titleId:10, status:1, title:title6
productId:6, productname: "product4", sellerName: "seller4",categoryId:7, titleId:36, status:1, title:title7
```

I have List of ProductTitle like the sampleData. Some item of list repeated sellerName, productName, categoryId and productId. I need to output like `List<Aggregate> list`. How can get this result with stream.

Sorry for my English

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Naman I have tried to do groupingBy for repeated field but its look like this `Map<Long, Map<Long,Map<String, Map<String,List< ProductTitle >>>>>` Im not sure this is correct way

Comment: you can take a look at the `groupingBy` approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62286431/1746118) and define a value mapping for products title to title info. If you attempt that and are stuck mid way, edit the question with your solution and ask what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first use the `groupingBy` approach with a `mapping` Collector for the values, and then `map` the resulting Map to the object you want.

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class x
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<ProductTitle> sampleData= Stream.of(
            new ProductTitle(1, "product1", "seller1", 2, 25, 1, "title1"),
            new ProductTitle(1, "product1", "seller1", 2, 23, 1, "title2"),
            new ProductTitle(1, "product1", "seller1", 2, 45, 1, "title3"),
            new ProductTitle(2, "product2", "seller2", 5, 67, 0, "title4"),
            new ProductTitle(2, "product2", "seller2", 5, 11, 1, "title5"),
            new ProductTitle(3, "product3", "seller3", 9, 10, 1, "title6"),
            new ProductTitle(6, "product4", "seller4", 7, 36, 1, "title7"));

        List<Aggregate>
                aggregateKeyListMap =
                sampleData.collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(ProductTitle::toKey, mapping(ProductTitle::toTitleInfo, toList())),
                        groupedByKey -> groupedByKey.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .map(entry -> new Aggregate(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                                .collect(toList())));
        aggregateKeyListMap.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static class ProductTitle
    {
        private Long   productId;
        private String productName;
        private String sellerName;
        private Long   categoryId;
        private Long   titleId;
        private int    status;
        private String title;
        private Long   titlePrice;

        public ProductTitle(long productId, String productName, String sellerName, long categoryId, long titleId, int status, String title) {
            this.productId = productId;
            this.productName = productName;
            this.sellerName = sellerName;
            this.categoryId = categoryId;
            this.titleId = titleId;
            this.status = status;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public AggregateKey toKey() {
            return new AggregateKey(productId, productName, sellerName, categoryId);
        }

        public TitleInfo toTitleInfo() {
            return new TitleInfo(titleId, status, title);
        }
    }

    @lombok.ToString(includeFieldNames = false)
    @lombok.EqualsAndHashCode
    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
    static class AggregateKey
    {
        Long   productId;
        String productName;
        String sellerName;
        Long   categoryId;
    }

    @lombok.ToString(includeFieldNames = false)
    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
    static class Aggregate
    {
        AggregateKey        key;
        List<TitleInfo> titles;
    }

    @lombok.ToString(includeFieldNames = false)
    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
    static class TitleInfo
    {
        Long   titleId;
        int    status;
        String title;
    }

}
```

For the sample data, it's yielding:

```
x.Aggregate(x.AggregateKey(6, product4, seller4, 7), [x.TitleInfo(36, 1, title7)])
x.Aggregate(x.AggregateKey(1, product1, seller1, 2), [x.TitleInfo(25, 1, title1), x.TitleInfo(23, 1, title2), x.TitleInfo(45, 1, title3)])
x.Aggregate(x.AggregateKey(3, product3, seller3, 9), [x.TitleInfo(10, 1, title6)])
x.Aggregate(x.AggregateKey(2, product2, seller2, 5), [x.TitleInfo(67, 0, title4), x.TitleInfo(11, 1, title5)])
```